# How to use route with specified parameters in pagination

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have two routes: one general route and one very specific. They have controller and action in common, but the special route has an additional parameter `special`:

```
$routes->connect('/special_products', ['controller' => 'Products', 'action' => 'index', 'special' => 1]);
$routes->connect('/products', ['controller' => 'Products', 'action' => 'index']);
```

This works as intended except for the pagination. If I am on the the `/special_products` page and click on page 2 I go to `/products?page=2` instead of the expected `/special_products?page=2`.

How could I change the routes or the pagination, so that the `special` parameter is not lost?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing your own control logic, I recommend that you use a search plugin. The two most popular are:

- [FriendsOfCake/search](https://github.com/friendsofcake/search)
- [CakeDC/search](https://github.com/friendsofcake/search)

Once you've configured it properly, you can use Query String to pass parameters to your action.

Your route would then look something like

```
$routes->connect('/special_products', [
    'controller' => 'Products', 
    'action' => 'index',
    '?' => ['special' => 1]
]);
```

Comment: The FoC Search plugin is awesome for CakePHP 3.0.

Comment: I use FoC Search plugin for search in my app (it's great, I agree!). I don't use it yet when I just want to select products by a parameter (like in the example above). I might reasearch this more, but please let me know if you have any information on this topic, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `$this->Paginator->options(['url' => $paginateUrl])` now you can pass params between pages

Here you have a simple example

**index.ctp**

```
<?= $this->Paginator->options(['url' => $paginateUrl]) ?>
<?= $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('previous')) ?>
<?= $this->Paginator->numbers() ?>
<?= $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >') ?>
```

**ProductsController**

```
public function index()
{
    ...
    if($this->request->param('special')) {

        $paginateUrl = ['special' => 1];

    }
    $this->set('paginateUrl', isset($paginateUrl) ? $paginateUrl : []);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I could make it work like that, though not entirely as expected. The links in the pagination have the form `/products?special=1&page=2`. That works but it would be much better if they had the form `/special_products?page=2`

Comment: @DavidAlbrecht try edititng routes solo like this:
`$routes->connect('/special_products/*', ['controller' => 'Products', 'action' => 'index'], ['special' => 1]);`

Comment: Adding /* to the route unfortunately didn't help with the pagination.